# "Error: FFMPEG not found": Error with simple Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

I'm using Windows (64-bit) with Node.js and npm installed.
In my project file, I have run the following commands:

```
npm init
npm install discord.js --save
npm install ffmpeg --save
```

Now i just created the code for a basic bot [here](https://hastebin.com/qarijerara.js) is the main code.
I list here the important:

```
 if (message.content === '!play' && message.member.roles.has(message.guild.roles.find("name", config.role_name).id)) {
    if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return log("?");
       message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function (connection){      
       });
 }
```

Then, in Discord, I say the following:

```
 [1517932146]  Musik bot loaded
    (node:35760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: FFMPEG not found
```

I have already tested the following:

- reinstallation of everything
- others of the require names e.t.z.
- simplify the code

So if you have any ideas then let me know.

### Solution

```
npm i ffmpeg-binaries@3.2.2-3
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317598/8412857)

Comment: you might want to paste your code properly, when you click that link it sends you to an empty hastebin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually install ffmpeg, the `ffmpeg` module on NPM simply exports a wrapper API for ffmpeg's command-line interface.

You can download ffmpeg's binaries [from the website](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) or use a package manager (like `apt` on Ubuntu, `brew` on Mac or `choco` on Windows) which usually takes care of dropping the binaries into a directory that is present in the `PATH`.

To install on `windows` using `choco`. Please ensure you running `cmd/windows powershell/ windows terminal` as `administrator` or it will fail here ...

`choco install ffmpeg`

To install on `linux`

`sudo apt install ffmpeg`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you never actually installed `ffmpeg`. Using the `ffmpeg` node module won't get you anywhere unless you [install the binaries.](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)

You can also use `apt`, `brew` or in your case `choco` which makes things go alot faster. [Here is a guide on how to do it in windows.](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ffmpeg)

Once it is installed you will be able to use many node modules such as `opusscript` and much more.