# Bot will not join voicechannel on boot

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to join a specific voice channel when it boots. I do see some ffmpeg errors but when i check if ffmpeg is installed through ffmpeg -version i get a response with no issues.

I've included my current snip of the code.

```
  let VoiceChannel = client.channels.get('561271325805641739')
  VoiceChannel.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=join) from discord.js, `voiceChannel.join()` method returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
// Join a voice channel
voiceChannel.join()
  .then(connection => console.log('Connected!'))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Using the snippet from the official documentation you should be able to debug the issue rather easily. I.e. either you are connected or you can read the error from the discord.js API.

Comment: Looks likle it says ReferenceError: voiceChannel is not defined

Comment: Meaning that a channel by that id doesn't exist. See [Collection.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get#Return_value), it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Not sure but the channel does exist and I just double checked the channel ID as well

Comment: I see; notice that in your own code, you have named `voiceChannel` with a captial `V` instead of lowercase `v`. What you can always do is console.log(`voiceChannel`), to see if it is defined.

Comment: I included a console.log(voiceChannel); and it is defined and has it's name "alerts" as well

Comment: In that case this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647177/error-ffmpeg-not-found-error-with-simple-discord-bot

Comment: Yep did this as well, have the ffmpeg dir at the root of the c drive, as well as set the PATH

Comment: I believe you have installed it. But your code can't find it. Did you reboot to resolve PATH? Otherwise, please move on to the other question i mentioned above, as we should discuss it in the already existing question. Their solutions also seem solid (also for Windows).