# FFMPEG not found error while attempting to implement ffmpeg into discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

While implementing a music feature into my node.js discord.js discord bot, I got an error claiming that it cant find FFMPEG. I reinstalled ffmpeg 3 times to no avail.

***This is the full error***

```
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403766+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: FFMPEG not found
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403797+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.selectFfmpegCommand (/app/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/ffmpeg/Ffmpeg.js:46:13)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403798+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at new FfmpegTranscoder (/app/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/ffmpeg/Ffmpeg.js:7:37)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403798+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at new MediaTranscoder (/app/node_modules/prism-media/src/transcoders/MediaTranscoder.js:10:19)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403799+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at new Prism (/app/node_modules/prism-media/src/Prism.js:5:23)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403799+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at new VoiceConnection (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceConnection.js:46:18)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403800+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/ClientVoiceManager.js:63:22
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403800+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403801+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ClientVoiceManager.joinChannel (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/ClientVoiceManager.js:45:12)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403801+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at VoiceChannel.join (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/VoiceChannel.js:130:30)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.403802+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.execute (/app/commands/play.js:31:64)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.404044+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
2020-02-17T01:48:30.404052+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

***This is the code***

```
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'initiates music methods of the bot',
    execute(msg, args){
        var servers = {};

        function play(connection, msg){
            var server = servers[msg.guild.id];

            server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
            server.queue.shift();

            server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                if(server.queue[0]){
                    play(connection, msg);
                }else{
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            });


        }
        if(!args[1]) return msg.channel.send("you need to provide a link");
        if(!msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to use this feature");
        if(!servers[msg.guild.id]) servers[msg.guild.id] = {
            queue: []
        }
        var server = servers[msg.guild.id];
        server.queue.push(args[1]);
        if(!msg.guild.voiceConnection) msg.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
            play(connection, msg);
        })
    }
}
```

I have no idea what the issue is. I am using heroku to deploy if that matters at all.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647177/error-ffmpeg-not-found-error-with-simple-discord-bot) solution will help you

Comment: thanks! I actually already saw that but opted to not attempt it since I deemed that it was unrelated but apparently that was exactly the issue.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of  ["Error: FFMPEG not found": Error with simple Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647177/error-ffmpeg-not-found-error-with-simple-discord-bot) ? (so the answer is marked as duplicate)