# Discord Bot: node-pre-gyp ERR

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, discord, discord.js

I really need help! So basically I'm transferring all my files to my new computer and when I ran the visual studio for discord bot it gave me loads of errors, i redownloaded nodejs and python and both are in path, then it gave me other errors, when I run it it says FFMPEG not found, so I install it and it gives this set of errors [image]

actually now it doesn't it just gives this
[image]

But when I run it it still gives this
[image]

And this is the log file of which i tried running npm repair
[log file](https://hastebin.com/dawuneloce.pl)

Comment: check if your Node.js versions is supported by node-pre-gyp that use are using.

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: Hi, please don't use screenshots to share code or error message, paste them directly in your question using code block.

Comment: You can check the node version you have by running `node -v` in your command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Error: FFMPEG not found": Error with simple Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647177/error-ffmpeg-not-found-error-with-simple-discord-bot)